# Dynamics Web Api - Get / Read Activities

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Is it even possible to get or read activities from an account using the web api? I can't find much related documentation.

Comment: I can't find enough detail in this question to answer it... in fact: I'm wondering whether this question even belongs here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to fetch activities belonging to a specific account.

The activities associated with an account are called [`Account_ActivityPointers`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607894.aspx). After [fetching a specific account](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607871.aspx#Anchor_1), you can then [`$expand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607871.aspx#Anchor_3) on the relevant entities:

```
/api/data/v8.0/accounts(<guid-here>)?$expand=Account_ActivityPointers
```